# Help with Wacom xsetwacom

Tags: wacom

i have a wacom cintiq 13 inch hd. the calibration for the width is off.
I am not sure what values to use.
the current value is: 400 400 59152 33448

I looked at this for help but I am still not sure what values are good.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wacom_tablet#Adjusting_aspect_ratios

My wacom is 1920 height and 1080 width.
the height seems to work fine, the ratio between the actual pixel dimensions and the xsetwacom dimension seems to be 30.6

1080 * 30.6 = 33448

I tried playing with the values, but it did not work.

I am using Xubuntu, is it better to use ubuntu with gnome instead?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by switching to villla Ubuntu with Gnome desktop